# Threads in C : Producers Consumers Deadlock Error

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, semaphore

i'm working on the producer consumer problem in C where i get the producers and consumers as input and i have to produce/consume 8192 elements.

My code is :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
sem_t empty;
sem_t full;
int prod=0;
int cons=0;
int buffer[8];
int in=0;
int out=0;

void producer(void* x)
{
  int z=1;
  while(z)
  {
    int item=rand();
    sem_wait(&empty);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (prod!=8192){
        buffer[in]=item;
        prod+=1;
        printf("Prod %d:item ins %d at %d\n",*((int *)x),buffer[in],in);
        in=(in+1)%8;
    }
    
    if(prod==8192){z=0;}
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&full); 
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++);
  }
}

void consumer(void*x)
{
int z=1;
 while(z)
 {
   sem_wait(&full);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (cons!=8192){
        int item = buffer[out];
        cons+=1;
        printf("Cons %d:item rm %d at %d\n",*((int *)x),item,out);
        out =(out+1)%8;
    }
   if(cons==8192){z=0;}

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   sem_post(&empty);
   for (int i=0; i<10000; i++);
 }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int nbProd=atoi(argv[1]);
    int nbCons=atoi(argv[2]);
    pthread_t produc[nbProd],conso[nbCons];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    sem_init(&empty,0,8);
    sem_init(&full,0,0);
    int idP[nbProd];
    for (int i=0; i< nbProd;i++){
        idP[i]=i;
    }
    int idC[nbCons];
    for (int i=0; i< nbCons;i++){
        idC[i]=i;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<nbProd;i++){
        pthread_create(&produc[i],NULL,(void *)producer,(void*)&idP[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<nbCons;i++){
        pthread_create(&conso[i],NULL,(void *)consumer,(void*)&idC[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<nbProd;i++){
        pthread_join(produc[i],NULL);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<nbCons;i++){
        pthread_join(conso[i],NULL);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    sem_destroy(&empty);
    sem_destroy(&full);
    printf("prod:%d,-cons:%d",prod,cons);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the different input as :
./main 3 3
./main 1 3
Most case of equals producers/consumers everything is fine
Case of inequals producers/consumers there is a deadlock situation.

I tried to find where does it come from with helgrind.
The output was talking about "Possible data race Locks held: none"
But i couldnt find the answer to this.

I expect my program to execute the producers/consumers problem for equals and inequals producers/consumers.

Comment: Have you tried running your code under a debugger?  The debugger should allow you to interrupt execution when the code appears to deadlock and provide you with backtraces for the various threads.

Comment: One obvious issue with the code is that the third parameter to [`pthread_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) should be of type `void *(*)(void *)` *not* `void (*)(void *)` as you have.  So your code, as it stands, is probably in the realms of undefined behaviour.

Comment: ... and casting to `void *` to disguise that issue does *only* that -- disguise it, not solve it.  And not reliably so, even, because C does not guarantee that function pointers can be converted to or from type `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

> Case of inequals producers/consumers there is a deadlock situation.

Running the program under GDB with `./a.out 1 3` arguments shows that there are 3 threads: the `main` thread blocked in `pthread_join` and two `consumer` threads blocked on `sem_wait(&full)`.

With that info the problem becomes *immediately obvious*: you start `full` at `0`, you increment it `nbProd` times, and you decrement it `nbCons` times.

When `nbCons > nbProd`, the decrements can not proceed and wait forever.

To fix this, you need to increment `full` `nbCons - nbProd` times to account for imbalance.